# Maintaining locale between Js and Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

I have an application which is Ruby on Rails/Devise front-end, and then Backbone.js. In app/views/layouts/application.html.erb I have this:

```
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
  I18n.locale = "<%= I18n.locale %>"
  I18n.defaultLocale = "<%= I18n.default_locale %>"
</script>
```

and then the user can select her own locale. Now, in the Ruby on Rails part, I have this, in the application controller:

```
class ApplicationController
before_filter :set_locale
  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end
  def default_url_options(options={})
    { :locale => I18n.locale }
  end
```

The problem I am having is that the Backbone.js piece doesn't "get" the locale from the Ruby on Rails piece, and the user has to select the locale again. How can I "inject" the locale into the Backbone.js piece so that the user doesn't have to choose it again?

More information: one of the comments is exactly right. The Javascript console shows that the Backbone.js piece isn't getting the locale from Ruby on Rails/Devise - the Javascript console shows the default at first. Somehow I am not passing the locale into Backbone.js.

Comment: I've used this approach before without issue. What exactly goes wrong? Is it perhaps because the `script` tag appears after you load your backbone models/views/etc.?

Comment: Does the browser javascript console get the value of I18n.locale right?

Comment: @mosch, thanks very much. Indeed, somehow I am not passing the I18n.locale into Backbone.js properly. Even if a user selects Spanish in Ruby on Rails, it doesn't get to Backbone.js.